# Are there interesting examples of distinct operations that associate?

Tags: associativity

I was just reading a text on first-order modal logic and found it very interesting to think of the distinction between rigid and non-rigid designators as a failure of associativity between the modal operator of, for instance $\mathcal{M},\Gamma\Vdash_v \Box F(c)$ and the valuation function.  If the valuation function is taken as primary then we get rigid designation, and otherwise we get non-rigid designation.

But this led me to wonder, are there any interesting examples of two distinct operations that associate?  I know the identity operation would associate with any other operation, and the "sends to 0" constant operation would associate with multiplication.  But these are both fairly uninteresting examples--are there others where you really learn something by noticing that the operations associate?  I suppose we could regard the constant multiple rule for derivatives and integrals as such an example, yes?

Comment: Can you state a bit more formally what you mean by "two operations associating"? The standard meaning of "associative" doesn't easily generalize to multiple operations that I can see...

Comment: I mean probably what you have in mind, that for operations $\ast$ and $\star$ and any $x,y,z$, we get $(x\ast y)\star z = x\ast (y\star z)$.  To make it more precise and general enough perhaps I can't phrase it in terms of operations but would have to instead phrase it in terms of function composition.  But I'm leaving the precise meaning somewhat open-ended intentionally, to leave room for all possible interesting answers.